# Android MediaPlayer IllegalStateException

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I am trying to play an audio file in Eclipse using MediaPlayer in Android programming.
I need to run the audio file (.wav or .mp3) which is saved on computer hard-drive. I have tried many things. I also tried copying the file in res folder of my project, but nothing worked. Below is my code. 
As you can see I have tried many ways and commented some. I was first getting IOException earlier. But after using MediaPlayer.create(), I am getting IllegalStateException.
Any help would be very appreciated.

```
public void playSound(MainActivity mainActivity){
    System.out.println("in playsound");
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;

     try {
         //fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Anupam-PC\\Downloads\\trailsoundfilerecordings\\jagmeet.wav");

         //mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
         System.out.println("inside try");
         //mp.setDataSource("/res/raw/hai.wav");
         //mp.setDataSource("C:\\Users\\Anupam-PC\\Downloads\\trailsoundfilerecordings\\jagmeet.wav");
         //mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.example.texttospeech/agreji.mp3");
         //mp.setDataSource("agreji.mp3");

         mp = MediaPlayer.create(mainActivity, R.raw.hai);
         System.out.println("after DS");
         mp.prepare();
         System.out.println("after prepare");
            mp.start();

           // fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally{
            try{
                fis.close();
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
```

Comment: Just as a side note, consider using the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class instead of `System.out.println(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement `mp.prepare();`, you have `create(/**/)`

This is my example that works like a charm:

```
class Vulcan implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
...

boolean isPrepearedToPlayAudio = false; 

mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.mini_vulcan_gun_1);

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);


public void stop(){

    mediaPlayer.pause();
}


public void start(){

    if(isPrepearedToPlayAudio){
               mediaPlayer.start();
       mediaPlayer.setLooping( true );
            } 
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    isPrepearedToPlayAudio = true;
}
```

Comment: Removing prepare works fine. But thanks a lot for your suggestion and sharing code example.

Comment: @user2552857 you can upvote, if you feel that it helped you. tnx

Comment: not able to do :(
it requires minimum 15 reputations and I just joined this forum and have 0 reputation.

Comment: @user2552857 you can set "V"

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation of `MediaPlayer.create(...)` already calls `prepare()`, and multiple calls to `prepare()` will cause an ISE. All you need to do is remove:

```
mp.prepare();
```

[Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.
>
> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result in an exception.